# A little different multiplication table

Tags: c#, multiplication

I'm struggling to create a multiplication table that would look like this:

```
 1 x 9 + 2 = 11
 12 x 9 + 3 = 111
 123 x 9 + 4 = 1111
 ......
 123456 x 9 + 8 = 11111111
```

Currently I managed do to this:

```
#region MTABLE

    for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        int number = 1 * 9 + i;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} X {1} + {2} = {3}  ", 1, 9, i, number);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
#endregion
```

And output that I get now:

```
1 X 9 + 2 = 11
1 X 9 + 3 = 12
1 X 9 + 4 = 13
1 X 9 + 5 = 14
1 X 9 + 6 = 15
1 X 9 + 7 = 16
1 X 9 + 8 = 17
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add number to 1 so next will be 12 and than next one 123...

If someone can give me any advice how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating a digit to a number can also be performed with multiplying with 10 and adding the digit:

```
int firstPart = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= 8; i++)
{
    int number = firstPart * 9 + i;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} X {1} + {2} = {3}  ", firstPart, 9, i, number);
    firstPart = firstPart * 10 + i;
}
```

Comment: Can also do `firstPart += number;` instead of `firstPart = firstPart * 10 + i;`

Comment: Oh my god how easy this looks.. i was searching on web for like 2 hours trying to find solution.. Anyway thank you so much for help.

Comment: @faca If the answer satisfies your question, please don't hesitate to accept it

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your formula (which is now set to 1) should be a variable outside the for loop scope and of type string. Each time you concatenate the i to this and then you do a Int.Parse of the string so you can multiply with it.